# Catching an incoming phone call in Google Glass

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-glass, incoming-call

I have a Google Glass paired to a phone running Android Lollipop, I want to use a Broadcast Receiver in Google Glass to handle an incoming call and eventually customize the call interface. I have been searching in the topics for more than two weeks but I have found nothing. Please any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware of you can try using the Android's TelephonyManager and PhoneStateListener to try to intercept incoming phone calls. It may or even may not work!!

All the best!!